# Teamviewer 9 does not have permission to launch in Ubuntu

Tags: teamviewer

I installed teamviewer 9 but when I try to launch it from terminal by typing teamviewer I get the following

```
Init...
/opt/teamviewer9/tv_bin/script/tvw_main: line 42: /home/cheng/.config/teamviewer9/logfiles/startup.log: Permission denied

Error: Init failed. Please check '/home/cheng/.config/teamviewer9/logfiles/startup.log'
```

The log file only contains the the following:

```
TeamViewer:        9.0.27891 - DEB
Profile:           /home/cheng (root)
Desktop:           DS: ''   XDG: ''
XServer TTY:       7

DistArch:          x86_64   ( Loader:   [X] ld32    [X] ld64 )
Distribution:
      Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
      Description:  Ubuntu 13.10
      Release:  13.10
      Codename: saucy
ok (info)

ok (profile)
```

How can I fix this? I can launch it with the command "sudo teamviewer" but I want it to be able to launch automatically when the computer starts.

Comment: I don't really know about the startup error, but here's a link on how to install it as a service, which makes it run at startup. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1471247

Answer (score 1):

- `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
- Put `teamviewer` before **exit 0**

/etc/rc.local is executed as **root** at Ubuntu Start-up